# best practise: Implementation of iAds to iPhone

Tags: iphone, xcode, iad, banner-ads

I'm trying to integrate iAds to iPhone app. It makes me very confusing.
my app got many view controllers with uitableviews.

*Should I integrate iAds at every view controller or
should I add it in mainwindow.xib (i add iAds codes to AppDelegate.h .m) or
should I create iAdsViewcontroller.h .m & .xib?*

if I add iAds to mianwindow.xib, how do i handle delegates like bannerViewDidLoadAd (need to resize uitableview according to bannerview is visibie or not).

If i integrate at every view controller, banner would be switching along with the app views. I read somewhere  if the app doesn't show an Ad for at least 30 seconds, it will lose ecpm.

Any thoughts will be appreciated... =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Apple iAd Documentation Best Practices](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/iAd_Guide/WorkingwithBannerViews/WorkingwithBannerViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009881-CH4-SW14)

Comment: oops... thanks for the doc. i should have read more detail. the apple sample code has everything i need for iAds implementation. =)